# Can I use a Mail Client Since I don't like the new Yahoo webmail layout?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client, yahoo-mail

I hate the way new Yahoo mail looks and also hate the way it operates. It has been very difficult browsing through my emails.

I dont want to change my email address so I am looking into alternatives. I considered following options:

1. Can I forward my mails to any other email address? If I do that, can I still send emails using my Yahoo email?
2. Can I use any client which can give me better organization of my emails?
3. Can I go back to previous version of Yahoo Mail?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can use a mail client with Yahoo. There's plenty of instruction on how to do it only a web-search away.  IE: https://www.google.com/search?q=use+yahoo+with+mail+client

Comment: Have you seen/tried this yet? [How to Get Old Yahoo Mail Back](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Get-Old-Yahoo-Mail-Back-391276.shtml) (From Oct, 2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a *free* webmail client from *any* provider, you're largely at *their* mercy, so if you're looking for a better user experience you may need to look for real mail client (product recommendations are off topic for here, but outlook and thunderbird are both popular). However, regardless of what client you pick you want to connect via IMAP and not POP3 to keep your mail safe on the remote servers.

See: [IMAP vs. POP3 vs. EXCHANGE](http://www.howtogeek.com/99423/email-whats-the-difference-in-pop3-imap-and-exchange/)

So to answer your three questions in reverse...

> Can I go back to previous version of Yahoo Mail?

Most likely not.

> Can I use any client which can give me better organization of my
>   emails?

While Yes in theory, you're safer sticking to an IMAP compatible client. Thunderbird is free, Outlook costs money. Either should provide an exponentially better experience than any webmail client could.

> Can I forward my mails to any other email address? If I do that, can I
>   still send emails using my Yahoo email?

Yes, sort of - this is easily done with a client where one program would check both, but send from one by default.

**See Also:**

http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/10/access-yahoo-mail-using-pop3-imap/